# Vim: regex in search function not working as expected to find left curly brackets

Tags: vim, curly-brackets

I am trying to compose a Vim script function to help format where the left braces are located at in C like functions blocks.

```
function! FixLeftBraces()
    "Set the cursor to the top of the file
    call cursor(1,0)
    while search(".\+{",'We') > 0
        exe "normal i\n\e"
    endwhile
endfunction
```

In this example my goal is to locate the left curly bracket that is on the same line as the function and relocate it to the next line. The `We` options prevent wrapping the file and reposition the cursor to the end of the search selection respectively.

When I perform a search in Vim using `/` mode entering in `/.\+{` performs a search and highlights lines that I expect it to in source code.

For example C lines such as:

```
//is highlighted
int main(){

//is not highlighted
void otherFuncion()
{
```

When I use the created `FixLeftBraces()` after sourcing it, it does not appear to work. It just runs and does nothing.

If I change the search to `search("{",'We')` then `FixLeftBraces()` runs but adds a new line after every left curly bracket. So I am confused why `FixLeftBraces()` does not work with the `search(".\+{",'We')`.

Comment: Try `echo ".\+{"`: you will see backslash disappear. Double it or use single quotes as @ib. did. By the way, in scripts it is better to use `normal!`, not `normal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the mentioned test cases, the `search()` function call keeps returning zero
and, therefore, the whole function does not work as expected.  The reason of
that is incorrectly specified pattern.  There are not a few special characters
that can be added into a double-quoted string constant using `\`-syntax (see
`:help expr-"`).  Consequently, the `\+` substring in the regexp literal is
interpreted as a single `+` character, and the original intention of the
pattern is mangled.

To avoid this undesirable behavior, escape the backslash symbol changing the
pattern string to

```
".\\+{"
```

or switch to single-quoted string literal where backslashes do not have
a special meaning (see `:help expr-'`),

```
'.\+{'
```